# "MySqlException: Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist" when executing MySQL stored procedures in .NET Core

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, ado.net

I am using the ADO.NET data provider `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` to access a MySQL database from .NET Core and most things work, but whenever I try to access a stored procedure I see the following exception message:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException : Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist
```

All of the articles I can find recommend running `mysql_upgrade` to fix the system tables, but this finds no problems.

And in fact the database does not contain a `mysql.proc` table - but [it is not supposed to since it is MySQL 8.0](https://ocelot.ca/blog/blog/2017/08/22/no-more-mysql-proc-in-mysql-8-0/)!

I've installed the latest version of Connector/NET (8.0.15) using MySQL Installer.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of Connector/NET installed is... irrelevant!

This is .NET Core, and ADO.NET data providers for .NET Core are obtained via NuGet - so make sure that your .NET Core project is loading the latest version of the `MySql.Data` NuGet package.

Older versions of the `MySql.Data` NuGet package (pre v.8) do give the above error when trying to access stored procedures on version 8+ MySQL databases.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this post trying to find a solution to this problem with my Azure-hosted MySQL database, but none of the solutions were applicable. I wanted to share what worked for me (from [rfontona's response here](https://www.nopcommerce.com/en/boards/topic/88906/table-mysqlproc-doesnt-exist-with-new-install)):

> Azure Database for MySQL – Single Server service, we have a gateway which runs v5.6 which may be cause this error. You can change the port in the connection string to 3309 (default would be 3306), which will connect you to v8.0 client in the gateway. More details here - [Supported versions - Azure Database for MySQL | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-supported-versions#connect-to-a-gateway-node-that-is-running-a-specific-mysql-version)

When setting up the MySqlConnectionStringBuilder, I used the following:

```
new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder {
   ...
   Port = 3309
}
```

I assume that a similar approach would work within a connection string as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you still face the issue after getting the latest version of MySql.Data package(s), make sure to add **CheckParameters=false**

Answer (score 0):

Check out the GetSchema function in ADO.Net in particular the "Procedures" and "Procedure Parameters" collections.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but in case this is question is still relevant...
I was able to get around this issue by changing the command type to text instead of a stored procedure and on the command text I used the call command:

```
sql = "call yourstoreproc()";
cmd = new Mysql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Hi Kenneth, I was just wondering, does updating `MySql.Data` not fix it? (It's always a shame to have to use work-arounds if avoidable - and this functionality definitely _should_ work - although it's always good to know what the work-arounds are if necessary, too!)

Answer (score 0):

As @MikeBeaton explained this is irrelevant version issue.
I had faced the same issue when deployed an application which was using mySql.data , and mySql.web dependencies as reference with version 6.0.. , then on deploying a machine that has connector with version 8.0 so it caused this error

**CONNECTOR VERSION ON HOSTING MACHINE**

[image]

**BIN FOLDER ASSEMBLY VERSION**

[image]

**SOLUTION**

Update your web.config and packages.config files with version from old to new

**EXAMPLE**

here the old version was 6.9.0 so I updated all with 8.0.21.0

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.21.0" newVersion="8.0.21.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

likewise find these all dependencies inside this and package file and replace all will solve your problem.